# Using golang present package to run ruby or python code

Tags: go, go-present

I used Golang present package to build a presentation. I'm able to run Golang code using `.play <file>.go` in my given .slide file.

I wonder if it's possible to run ruby or python code too using `.play <file>.rb` or `.play <file>.py` ?

> I tried above method but it's giving me error when I click on **Run**
>   button in browser. Is it possible to run code for other languages ? If
>   Yes, how ? If No, Why not ?

**check.rb**:

```
puts 'hello, world'
```

**Here is the code for my example.slide file:**

```
Checking the working of Ruby Code
Nothing much here!
15:04 2 Jan 2006
Tags: Ruby, Golang

Piyush Chauhan
********************
********************
********************
@piyushpsycho

* Title of slide or section (must have asterisk)

Some Text

.play check.rb

** Subsection

- bullets
- more bullets
- a bullet with
```

Comment: Did you take a look at how package present runs code?

Comment: I tried using this, but I got this error:
`2015/01/14 20:02:10 bad websocket origin: http://localhost:3999`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Present uses a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) comment to determine the program to run. Change your script to:

```
#! /usr/bin/ruby
puts 'hello, world'
```

Comment: I tried using this, but I got this error:
`2015/01/14 20:02:10 bad websocket origin: http://localhost:3999`

Comment: @PiyushChauhan It works for me. Are you viewing the presentation at http://localhost:3999 or some other URL?

Comment: Yup got the error, I was accessing it on `http://localhost:3999` which is giving me bad websocket origin error. When I switched to `http://127.0.0.1:3999`, it's working fine. Can you think why it's happening, not able to connect to websocket on `http://localhost:3999` ?

Comment: @PiyushChauhan By default, the websocket package returns the above error if the request Host header is not equal to the request Origin header. I don't understand why, but somehow your browser is using two host names for the present server (127.0.0.1 and localhost). Maybe the browser resolves localhost to 127.0.0.1 for only one of the headers. Weird.

Comment: is it possible to run node.js code, tried changing the the she bang, but no luck